# How to remove settings in the toolbar?

Tags: android, settings, toolbar

[image: How to remove Settings]

I want to remove only the setting points without affecting other properties in the toolbar.
What can I do here is part of my manifest:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main_met_calc" />
```

Comment: Do you mean the 3 dots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just delete the first  entry in the menu.xml

The path where's menu.xml is app/src/main/res/menu

the item xml will look like this

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much: it works!! - after I had deleted id action_settings in the options menue.

Comment: @blg im glad it helped you, can you please mark it as answer then?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to remove the menu creation, by empty overriding of onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: In my case I was inflating a layout before returning true. Removing that fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Follow this image]

The path where's menu.xml is app/src/main/res/menu

Remove this below code

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_settings"
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:showAsAction="never"
android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much: it works!! - after I had deleted id action_settings in the options menue.